# When i am trying fetch api from node js it is not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, twilio

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
   import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
   import { useAppContext } from "./context/appContext";
   import Video from "twilio-video";
   import Room from "./components/Room/Room";
   import { Home, Header } from "./components/index";

   app.post("/video/token", (req, res) => {
     const identity = req.body.identity;
     const room = req.body.room;
     const token = videoToken(identity, room, config);
     sendTokenResponse(token, res);
   });
```

In the above section i made api endpoint in node js /video/token but when i fetch it in React js it's give an error

```
const data = await fetch("/video/token", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        identity: username,
        room: roomName,
      }),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    }).then((res) => res.json());
```

And the above code is fetching the api and it is returning Promise  **Unexpected token < at JSON position 0**

```js
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
   import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
   import { useAppContext } from "./context/appContext";
   import Video from "twilio-video";
   import Room from "./components/Room/Room";
   import { Home, Header } from "./components/index";

   app.post("/video/token", (req, res) => {
     const identity = req.body.identity;
     const room = req.body.room;
     const token = videoToken(identity, room, config);
     sendTokenResponse(token, res);
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `async` and `await` together, not only ***await***

```
async function sendData(){
    await fetch("/video/token", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        identity: username,
        room: roomName,
      }),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    }).then((res) => res.json());
}
```

Comment: Yes i am using there async also by using useCallback function of react

Answer (score 0):

this happens because you are trying to parse api response as json which is not a json

> res.json()

here you should first check api response if its json or not.

Comment: Yes it's a json

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that your server is not responding with the correct response. That's why you're getting the error `Unexpected token < at JSON position 0`. The first character of the response is a `<` which implies that it is an HTML response, possibly with an error message within.

You should inspect the response that you are getting and see whether that tells you more about the error.

Also, make sure you are running the server side as well as running the client side. If the server isn't running, then you will definitely get errors from your fetch from the front-end.